# Channel with more controlled permission per organization in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have 2 organization say org1 and org2. I would like to create a channel which gives full access to org1 and read only to org2. Can some one tell me on how in hyperledger fabric.

I have already created a TwoOrg channel as per https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#understanding-the-docker-compose-topology. But I wanted to make org1 alone have write permission.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, didnt find it. Am looking for alternatives to hyperledger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [update the configuration](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_update.html) of the channel to change the access rights of org2 to read (instead of write).

Comment: But in that link no where it mentions about how to make the organization read only. Could you give me an example config file.